# why emulator is not receiving gcm notification?

Tags: android

I am using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) in my android app. I get the reg id from gcm but my application is not receiving GCM notification. I am following this tutorial http://techlovejump.com/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/. And testing my app on emulator. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using an emulator with the Google APIs (when you create the AVD you are given the choice of using standard Android, or the ones including the Google APIs).

Answer (score 1):

GCM works only if Google Play services are installed on your device.
See this for installing gplay http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-install-google-play-services-on-android-emulator-genymotion/

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

1. Make sure there is a Google account added to the emulator.

It doesn't have to be any account (like the senderId) in particular.

If the emulator is running Android 4.0.4 or later, this step is optional as GCM does not require an account from this version on.

2.AVD configured with at least Google API Level 8 (or above) and Android 2.2 (or above).

Comment: I have added google account in emulator and it is running 4.4.2. also api level is 19